# It is possible to compile with Api 23 (6.0) and to maintain the old permission system (install-time)?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-api-levels

I readed this in the official android blog:

> **Permission Changes**  With Marshmallow, permissions have moved from
> install-time to runtime. This is a mandatory change for SDK 23+,
> meaning it will affect all developers and all applications targeting
> Android 6.0.

So... it is possible to mantain the old permission system if you compile with Android 6.0 (api 23) but you target Android 4.4 (api 20)?

I mean doing this:

```
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }
```

The requisites of my project for now are to maintain the old permission system and to target sdk version 20 (because I need to maintain the old notification system and if you target sdk version higher than 20 you must use the new notification system). So... can I compile with Api 23 and maintain old permission system if I target sdk version 20?

Comment: The `targetSdkVersion` should be what decides if the new permission model is used or not. This seems really easy to test though; just run the app on a device (or emulator) running Android 6.0 or later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes the old permission system will be used (even on Android 6.0) if `targetSdkVersion` is set <23. However an user on Android 6.0 can later manually disable individual permissions from **Settings**. Although Android 6.0 will warn the user when they try to do that but they can revoke anyway.

Now the question is **will your app crash after user revokes permission?**

> When we call a function that requires a permission user revoked on
>   application with `targetSdkVersion` less than 23, no Exception will
>   be thrown. Instead it will just simply do nothing. For the function
>   that return value, it will return either null or 0 depends on the
>   case. Although application would not be crashed from calling a
>   function. It may still can crash from what that application does next
>   with those returned value.

Comment: This was a very important piece of information for our project, where we are running our app not a phone, but on a a Qualcomm Snapdragon chipset based board which is running Android 6. we can't set permissions since there is no display, its a headless setup. I just changed targetSDK to 22 and now the app doesn't ask for permissions. Thanks a lot for your answer. The board manufacturers should have disabled the permissions module altogether from their Android image, which I am sure they'll have to do eventually otherwise these boards without a display will be not very practical in future.